# URL to Cloudstorage file on sdk

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I am experimenting with Google Cloud Storage on Appengine. I installed the new cloudstorage python api code and have everything working well. I deployed my code, and it is also working well.

My ACL is (correctly) set to public-read and I can view my added files on http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com// just fine when calling cloudstorage on the appspot.

However, is there a similar path on the local sdk?

I am using this to upload images and create thumbnails. However, locally, I don't know how to serve up the url to the thumbnail. I do see in the blobstore viewer, the blobs are created, but there is no filename displyed in the blobinfo AND the url uses the blobstore key rather than the filename I gave to the gs create call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the following on the app server:

```
/_ah/gcs/[bucket name]/[filename]
```

If you used the default bucket, it's called `app_default_bucket`.

I've tested it with images and it works well. With mp4 videos it seems to run into an error though.